# FlatList - Item in FlatList is not order

Tags: react-native

I have list out the nested array of items using FlatList. The items are not properly arranged. Please correct me where I went wrong.

```
<FlatList
      contentContainerStyle={{alignSelf: 'center'}}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      horizontal={false}
      data={getProduct}
      numColumns={2}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
        return item.id;
      }}
      renderItem={({item, index}) => (
        <View style={{backgroundColor: COLORS.yellow}}>
          {item.product.map((v, i) => (
            <View key={v.id} style={{backgroundColor: COLORS.white}}>
              {v.image.map((im, k) => (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate('CatProdDetail', {
                      prodname: v.productName,
                      catname: v.subcateName,
                      price: v.sellingPrice,
                      img: im.image,
                    });
                  }}
                  style={{
                    height: 220,
                    width: screenWidth / 2.3,
                    backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
                    borderRadius: 15,
                    margin: 5,
                    elevation: 3,
                  }}>
                  <View key={im.id}>
                    <View
                      style={{
                        height: 120,
                        width: 100,
                        alignSelf: 'center',
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                      }}>
                      <Image
                        style={{
                          height: '100%',
                          width: '100%',
                          resizeMode: 'contain',
                        }}
                        source={{uri: `${APILINKS.IMG_URL}${im.image}`}}
                      />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{margin: 10}}>
                      <Text
                        numberOfLines={3}
                        style={{
                          fontSize: 11,
                          color: COLORS.black_100,
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins-SemiBold',
                        }}>
                        {v.productName}
                      </Text>
                      <Text
                        style={{
                          fontSize: 10,
                          color: COLORS.grey,
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium',
                        }}>
                        {v.subcateName}
                      </Text>
                      <Text
                        style={{
                          fontSize: 12,
                          color: COLORS.black_100,
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins-SemiBold',
                        }}>
                        RM {v.sellingPrice}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ))}
            </View>
          ))}
        </View>
      )}
    />
```

without  numColumns={2}

Comment: I guess in the array you are getting the new added items first, that's why they are displaying before the previous items. You should reverse the array so the last items display before the newly added items

Comment: Shall I add the Json response?

Comment: yes please add the json

Comment: added, please check

Comment: aah, It is in order. can u remove numColumns attribute from flatlist. or change it to 1 then let me know

Comment: But I want two items

Comment: yeah but it just for testing, I want to see if we remove column from Flatlist then it comes in order or just come randomly like now

Comment: now it's like single item. Screenshot added.

Comment: data={items.sortBy(this.props.todos, item => item.date)}

use this kind of logic to display your items sorting by a date.